# Matlab eps bug camlight

Tags: matlab, png, figure, lighting

I was wondering, if anyone know the solution to this problem. When I use the camlight option within my program in order to light up the scene and then save a graphic as a png figure, this happens

[image]

Obviously, the lighting on the left is strange, but what is the problem ?

On the right, where the picture is taken from, the lighting is correct

thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't look like a PNG problem.  What happens if you save it in another format such as JPEG (not suggesting that you actually use JPEG as your finished product, but just now to help diagnose the problem)?

Comment: does not change anything. I am using the print function of matlab btw

Comment: Does the eps file incur the same problem?